# Can't open Datepicker using calendar button

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's my code:

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control date" id="startDate" placeholder="Start Date" ng-click="date.startDate=true"  datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="date.start" is-open="date.startDate" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="date.startDate=true" is-open="date.startDate"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
</p>
```

For some reason, I can't get the calendar button to open the datepicker up... I thought hvaing just ng-click would work but that isn't working.

Here is the controller code:

```
self = this;
self.open = function ($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    self.opened = {};
    self.opened[$event.target.id] = true;

    // log this to check if its setting the log    
    console.log(self.opened);
};
```

Comment: This example looks very similar to the example from the UI-Bootstrap docs.  Where's your controller declared?